# Como colocar auto incremento no php myadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estou usando o PHP my admin, mas n está aparecendo a opção de auto incremento, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Qual versão do PhpMyAdmin vc está usando ? Sem detalhar melhor fica difícil te ajudar ;)
Leitura recomendada: [tour] e [mcve]

Comment: Tô usando a versão 4.5.2, em versões passadas, na criação de uma tabela, tinha a coluna 'extra' onde era colocado o auto incremento, mas nessa nova versão não encontro está opção

Answer (score 1):

Na criação de uma tabela e sua estrutura, tem uma opção chamada A_I que é a Auto Increment, daí vc seta a a coluna como primária etc!

Comment: Valeu, me ajudou muito Sampaio Leal, obrigado

Comment: de nada amigo, se puder dar um voto ai, porque toda vez que posto algo alguem da rep- parece que me odeiam eu ein